# How should I have addressed this old comment answer?

Tags: support

On [When to apply XP in Pathfinder?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/15726/when-to-apply-xp-in-pathfinder?noredirect=1#comment146151_15726) there is a comment answer which, unfortunately, I think is an important answer because it provides the only RAW information on the topic.  This information is not addressed by any of the (many) existing answers, and, in fact, many of them make unsourced and completely inaccurate claims as to the default state of the system.  The comment is highly upvoted, but rather than upvoting a comment answer, which seems inappropriate, I wanted the answer put as an actual answer.  My options at that point, it seemed to me, were:

1) copy-paste the answer and post it myself, with some spruced up formatting.

2) leave a comment asking the original author to re-post as an answer.

3) Do nothing.

4) Flag the comment answer for deletion.

I know that, on 'not old' questions at least, option two is a community accepted response to a comment answer you agree with and which is substantial enough that there isn't much not-fluff you should add to it.  Option 4 is the other community accepted response, which is used on the normal half-assed kind of comment answers.  Option 1 is used if the comment answer is very incomplete and you can add substantive material to it in the process of forming an actual answer.  Option 3 is always acceptable, but doesn't get anything done.

Because I was not aware that we treated older (non-historic locked) questions differently *at all*, I chose option 2.  **What should I have done instead and why?**

Comment: Have you considered editing the link from the comment into the accepted answer?  That answer includes an "after the session" provision, where the link to the PF website could be fit in.

Answer (score 2):

As always, there's not a black and white answer, there's just using judgement.

The older the question is, the less useful "subtle" intervention (comments etc) are. In fact, they can be counterproductive because when you bump a question to the top like that, it might get comment-reaped.  In this case 7 upvotes on a comment stayed my hand on that count. But when an exchange is more than 3 years old, it's likely it's off the radar of people (often the users involved aren't even around any more).

The older a question is, IMO the more you should "crap or get off the pot" in terms of necro'ing it - make a meaningful change (add the answer yourself, edit) or leave it alone. You're welcome not to - but I have to say personally, I've gotten a lot of your old comments about some minor point of order pop to me on my super old Q/As on main and meta and often I find it annoying and out of context and don't bother to address them.

It's not that you *can't* leave a comment like that on an old question - just that it's unlikely to be helpful, as it will have a high chance of either being unseen or being "too little, too late" to bother with.

Comment: What do you mean by "comment-reaped?" I'm unfamiliar with the term.

Comment: @nitsua60 That means all the comments go away.

Comment: @doppelgreener by a bot, or as a mod-reflex?

Comment: @nitsua60 Mod reflex. We don't have automated comment deletion.

Comment: @mxyzplk You're talking about the dark wanderer bumping a question to the top, but as far as I can tell the only bumping action that took place recently was [Rob's edit](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/15726/when-to-apply-xp-in-pathfinder/15731#15731). Dark Wanderer never did any bumping.

Comment: @doppelgreener that's just cause I got to the question in the first place via the 'active' tab.  I haven't been avoiding bumping things, though, cause I didn't feel like there's any difference between new questions and old ones.  I usually check to see when a user was last active before leaving a comment if I don't recognize them and the question is older than a couple days, but nothing otherwise.  I'll try to avoid working on older questions now that I realize necroing is a thing here, culturally, and avoid marking Q's as dupes if the dupe is old.

Comment: necroing is OK - but just do something substantive. random comments on old questions are write-only.

Comment: The complaints about bumping (both here and in response to the comment in place) confuse: don’t comments specifically *not* bump anything? Is some different meaning of “bump” that I’m unfamiliar with being employed here? Or do new comments bring a question up in some cases?